# Commit a file to git repository using Stash (bitbucket server) REST API

Tags: git, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am using Atlassian Stash (Bitbucket server) to manage my git repository. Recently I had a requirement to commit a file (a newly created .xml file) to my Git repository using the [Stash REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.11.6/stash-rest.html). I've gone through the documentation, but it seems like the REST API doesn't support that functionality.

Am I correct, or is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 7):

Probably you are looking for

[PUT /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/browse/{path:.*}](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/5.4.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm140014937011952)

From the documentation of API

> PUT
>   /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/browse/{path:.*}
>
> Update the content of path, on the given repository and branch. This
>   resource accepts PUT multipart form data, containing the file in a
>   form-field named content. An example curl request to update
>   'README.md' would be:
>
> > curl -X PUT -u username:password -F  content=@README.md  -F
> >     'message=Updated using file-edit REST API'  -F branch=master -F 
> >     sourceCommitId=5636641a50b http://example.com/rest/api/latest/projects/PROJECT_1/repos/repo_1/browse/README.md
>
> - branch: the branch on which the path should be modified or created
> - content: the full content of the file at path message: the message
>     associated with this change, to be used as the commit message. Or null
>     if the default message should be used.
> - sourceCommitId: the commit ID
>     of the file before it was edited, used to identify if content has
>     changed. Or null if this is a new file.
>
> The file can be updated or
>   created on a new branch. In this case, the sourceBranch parameter
>   should be provided to identify the starting point for the new branch
>   and the branch parameter identifies the branch to create the new
>   commit on.

Comment: question: how to commit multiple files in single commit using bitbucket api?

Comment: I am not aware if there is any API for supporting multiple files in single commit. Refers to [atlassian developer](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/)

Answer (score 5):

This cannot be done via the Stash/Bitbucket Server REST API. I had to move to [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), which is a Java wrapper for communication between GIT and Application.

The question *[Is it possible to commit a file to a remote base repository using JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114690/is-it-possible-to-commit-a-file-to-a-remote-base-repository-using-jgit)* has more information.